# TypedMultipleChoiceField and CheckboxSelectMultiple edit (view) form with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using this code:

```
FORMA_INGRESSO_CHOICES = (
('AG','Agendado'),
('EN','Enem'),
('PR','Prova'),
('AC','Análise de Currículo'),
('RD','Redação'),
('VG','Vagas'),
)
Forma_Ingresso = forms.TypedMultipleChoiceField(choices=FORMA_INGRESSO_CHOICES,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple());
```

And I'm using django admin. This record is saved perfectly in db, but when I'm editing, checkbox's doesn`t "load" saved info.

If I use this choices,

```
FORMA_INGRESSO_CHOICES = (
(1,'Agendado'),
(2,'Enem'),
(3,'Prova'),
(4,'Análise de Currículo'),
(5,'Redação'),
(6,'Vagas'),
)
```

Everything works pretty.

In my db, I have this lists for two cases:

```
[u'AG',u'EN'] and [u'1',u'2']
```

Whit chars doesn´t work, whit integer works.

Can you help me please?﻿